# How to obtain the authorization code required for User Credentials through the cURL's command line

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I trying to use GCS "User Credentials" to connect to Google cloud storage using libcurl library.
"User Credentials" authentication needs Client Id & Secret key to connect to GCS, but in this process Authentication Code also needs to be generated.

I need to generate this Authentication code using cURL.
Can anyone help me ??

Answer (score 0):

The **Client ID** you mentioned is the same as the **Authentication ID** and can only be generated from either the [Cloud Console's Credentials Page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?_ga=2.92235294.-526629171.1559581261) or via the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

If you are trying to generate an **Access Token** (OAUTH2_TOKEN), you will need to complete an authentication flow to authorize requests as a user. Cloud Storage uses [OAuth 2.0 for API authentication and authorization](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication).

Here's what you need to do to get an authorization access token from the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/):

1. Select & authorize APIs (Cloud Storage)
2. Select the scope for the APIs you would like to access or input your own OAuth scopes, e.g.: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write`
3. Then click the "**Authorize APIs**" button
4. Once you've got the Authorization Code click the "**Exchange authorization code for tokens**" button, you will get a refresh and an access token which is required to access OAuth protected resources.
5. Grab the **Access Token** to use in your cURL command
6. Then configure your request to Cloud Storage API by constructing your HTTP request like so (upload):

   `curl -X POST --data-binary @[OBJECT_LOCATION] \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer [OAUTH2_TOKEN]" \
   -H "Content-Type: [OBJECT_CONTENT_TYPE]" \
   "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/[BUCKET_NAME]/o?uploadType=media&name=[OBJECT_NAME]"`

You can have a look at this [Cloud Storage upload example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) in our public docs to guide you with constructing a request and testing it out.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to make the calls 1 to 4 using cURL rather than manual steps...
Only one thing, Can I use API Keys for Bucket operations ??

Comment: You cannot use cURL to skip over step 1 to 4. You can programmatically perform those steps using the Client Library and basically just use the OAuth flow.

As for using the API key for GCS bucket operations, no you cannot use it. API key is for like tracking mostly, not authentication nor authorization. It cannot prove who you are.